# Sorting a set in least number of steps

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, order-theory, directed-graphs

**Question:** Given a totally ordered set $S = \{ a_1, a_2, a_3, \cdots a_{32} \}$. Assume that we don't know the order but can determine the order between two elements by a query. Show that we can determine the relations between all the $32$ elements it completely in $15$ **'steps'**. Where a **'step'** is defined below:

One step involves any number of queries of the form is $a_i > a_j$. The only condition is that in a particular step each $a_i may occur in at most one such.

**Progress so far**: I have not been able to make any significant progress I think. I have tried recurrences, matchings and so on. But I think the main problem is, I have not been able to exploit the transitivity of orders to minimize my steps needed.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich By sorting I meant determining the order between all the 32 elements...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich One, step may involve several queries, where each query is a question of the form is a_i > a_j . The only condition is that in a particular step, one $a_i$ can appear in at most one such query

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich  Please, let me know if the question makes sense now.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I have changed the question to, we want to determine the all the relations between the a_i. I am not trying to sort the array.

Comment: Are you sure this is possible at all? Your queries are binary, so after 15 steps, you will have gathered information about at most 30 items, so you will not have compared two of those with anything else.

Comment: @Ekin I dont have 15 queries, I have 15 steps. Each step is  a collection of queries. such that in each step, every element can be queried can be involved in at most one query.

Comment: I would recommend doing a websearch for "parallel sorting algorithms".

Comment: Have you followed up on my suggestion, Subham?

Comment: Are you still here, Subham?

Comment: @GerryMyerson , Sorry for the late reply. Yes, I got it https://www.slideshare.net/richakumari37266/parallel-sorting-algorithm#:~:text=3.,to%20get%20the%20correct%20result. page explains it well on slide 11-12

Comment: Good. So if you now understand how to solve the problem, you could write it up and post it as an answer.

Comment: Today would be a good day to do that.